# FragmentTransaction skips the last ~25%

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, animation

I am having two Fragments. One List and one with the clicked list item. When I swipe the list item out, the animation is smooth for the first ~75%, but for the last ~25% it just "skips" the Fragment out very quickly compared to the rest of the animation. This is my code.

SwipeView.java

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(view.getContext()){
    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_out_right, 0, 0)
                .hide(fm.findFragmentByTag("SwipeView"))
                .show(fm.findFragmentByTag("NativeList"))
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
});
```

slide_out_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="-1000"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

It is intentional that the new fragment is not supposed to move. Is there anyway to make the animation for the Fragment that is going out to have the same pace for the entire way?

Comment: What support libs version are you using?

Comment: Well none for this part.